# Using a string as a variable name

Tags: python

I'm collecting a lot of form parameters.  Instead of writing repetitive lines like this:

```
def post(self):
    var1 = self.request.get('var1')
    var2 = self.request.get('var2')
    var3 = self.request.get('var3')
    var4 = self.request.get('var4')
        ...
```

...Is there a way to put this into a loop?  Perhaps something like this:

```
def post(self):
    var_list = ['var1', 'var2', 'var3', 'var4', ...]
    for var in var_list:
        var = self.request.get(var)
```

The problem with my loop is that var is a string and I need it to actually be a variable name on the last line.  How could I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have written will work, but you are overwriting the value in the assignment, since you repeat `var`. Instead, collect the results in a list:

```
def post(self):
    var_list = ['var1', 'var2']
    result_list = []
    for var in var_list:
        result_list.append(self.request.get(var))
    return result_list # etc.
```

You can further simplify it by using a list comprehension:

```
def post(self):
    return [self.request.get(var) for var in ['var1', 'var2']]
```

Comment: Or, they could put it in a `dict`.

Comment: @SethMMorton `request.get` seems to be a dict-like object already, so not sure what would be the point of that.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a list instead:

```
def post(self):
    vars_list = []
    var_list = ['var'+str(i) for i in range(1,10)]
    for var in var_list:
        vars_list.append(self.request.get(var))
```

Comment: You're overwriting the builtin `vars()`

Answer (score 0):

Define `MAX_VAR_NUM` and use the following:

```
MAX_VAR_NUM=1000
var = [self.request.get("var"+str(i)) for i in xrange(1,MAX_VAR_NUM)]
```

You can add MAX_VAR_NUM as an attribute for the object instance:

```
var = [self.request.get("var"+str(i)) for i in xrange(1,self.max_var_num)]
```